# HIVE - Removing everything between certain characters

Tags: sql, regex, hive, regexp-replace

I have some paths as strings that I would like to clean and make more neat.

Example of strings:
String 1: `/keywordOneA/keywordTwoA/393r-mr49-j5n65_9e8e77g77b8`
String 2: `/keywordOneA/keywordTwoA/111-4444-jjjj_1b1b1b1b1b1b1b`
String 3: `/keywordOneA/keywordTwoB/393r-mr49-j5n65_9e8e77g77b8/keywordThreeA`

I want them to yield:
String 1: `/keywordOneA/keywordTwoA/`
String 2: `/keywordOneA/keywordTwoA/`
String 3: `/keywordOneA/keywordTwoB/keywordThreeA`

Basically as long as it is just LETTERS between `/`...`/` Then I want to keep these keywords otherwise I want to remove them. Is this possible somehow?

Also possible to do this stepwise using `WITH`clause.

This is what I have come up with, but starting to get stuck

```
select regexp_replace('/keywordonea/keywordtwob/393r-mr49 j5n65_9e8e77g77b8/keywordthreea','[0-9\/_.,!?-]','');
```

Comment: Try `\b[a-z0-9-_]+\b\/?` https://regex101.com/r/vYXbGX/1

Comment: @S.Kablar - Seems to struggle with "words" that end with a hyphen...  https://regex101.com/r/vYXbGX/5

Comment: To my knowledge I will not have any words ending with anything other than a digit or letter.
But I am not 100% sure actually. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do what you want:

```
select regexp_replace(val, '/[^/]*[^a-zA-Z0-9/][^/]*', '')
```

I don't have Hive on-hand, but [this works in Oracle](http://rextester.com/GDHI15231).

This regular expression is looking for characters following a forward slash.  These characters are not forward slashes and at least one must be non-alphanumeric.  Because regular expressions are greedy by default, this will match the characters to the next forward slash or to the end of the string.

Comment: @wp78de . . . Did you click on the rextester example?  No, it does not.

Comment: Did you? "This Page is not reachable" - you have a typo in your URL.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Many thanks to you! You understood my question correctly and solved it well :D

If you have time, It would be wonderful if you could explain more in detail what every step contributes with. Example
[^/] #String starts with a "/"
* # zero or more matches of 
...
...
I think many would learn from it :D

How would one continue to build on this? Say I would like to also allow for case where I only have digits between the slashed e.g. '/123456789/'.
This one worked, `'/[^/]*[^a-zA-Z0-9/][^/]*|/[0-9][^/]*' `for some cases, but not sure it is stable enough.

Thank you!

Comment: @GordonLinoff Also, Do you have any good sources of litterature (web, books, articles) etc. on regexp for hive. I do not find that many examples when I google.

Comment: @TKN - Don't search for regular expressions on hive, just search for regular expressions.  Where there are distinctions *(such as Perl Style RegExps)*, Hive uses Java's regular expressions *(java.util.regex.Matcher : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)*

Comment: @TKN : Literally, what this expressions does : Find a `/`, then multiple characters that are not `/` *(`*` means "0 or more")*, then exactly one character that's not `a-z` or `A-Z` or `0-9` or `/`, then multiple characters that are not `/`.

Comment: @TKN : More meaningfully, what that means is...  A sequence of characters that starts with `/` then none of the following characters are `/` *(so, up to the next `/`, or the end of the string)*, and at least of of them is also not ( `a-z` or `A-Z` or `0-9` ).